# MDX calculated measure by dimension value

Tags: ssas, mdx, dimensions, calculated-field, fact

I have to filter the measure value by a value in a the article group dimension.

Starting point:

**Facts:**

- Inventory (only opening stock of a month)
- Sales

**Dimensions:**

- Articlegroup (content: articlegroup types: Service or not)
- Article
- Time

We have 2 types of sale:

- Standard sale (affects invetory)
- Service (doesn't affects inventory)

My MDX-Script calculates dynamically the daily stock over a month.
The problem is that service-sales should not affects the inventory,
so my script have to filter the measure value.

Such like:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[FilteredAmount]
AS (SELECT [Measures].[SalesAmount] FROM [Cube]
    WHERE [Article Group].[Service].&[0])
-- Service "0" = not service

CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[Amount]
AS [Measures].[OStockAmount] - [Measures].[FilteredAmount]
```

I don't know how to filter the value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
CREATE MEMBER CURRENTCUBE.[Measures].[FilteredAmount]
AS ([Measures].[SalesAmount], [Article Group].[Service].&[0]);
-- Service "0" = not service
```

That creates a tuple that just retrieves a section of the cube... Measure SalesAmount and Service=0

Comment: @Blin4ik glad to help! One way you could express your thanks is by [accepting the answer](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the checkmark.